# Wpf Button Style is not applied

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window that has tow group boxes, each group box has 3 buttons, all of the buttons apply the 3 styles. the styles is:

```
<Style x:Key="SaveButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" >            
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DockPanel>                       
                <Image Source="/SalesSolution;component/Images/save.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" />                        
                <Label Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" />
            </DockPanel>                    
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
</Style>


<Style x:Key="UpdateButtonStyle" TargetType="Button"  >
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DockPanel>
                <Image Source="/SalesSolution;component/Images/Refresh_font_awesome.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Label Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button"  >
    <Setter Property="Content">                    
        <Setter.Value>
            <DockPanel>
                <Image Source="/SalesSolution;component/Images/delete.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Label Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
</Style>
```

The buttons' XAML code:

```
//These three buttons do not applied  the styles:
     <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="buttonCompanySave" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="buttonCompanySave_Click" Margin="188,215,0,323" Style="{StaticResource SaveButtonStyle}" />
     <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="buttonCompaniesUpdate" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="buttonCompanyUpdate_Click" Margin="188,274,0,264" Style="{StaticResource UpdateButtonStyle}" />
     <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="buttonCompanyDelete" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="buttonCompanyDelete_Click" Margin="188,333,0,205" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" />



//These three buttons apply the styles:
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="buttonItemSave" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="buttonItemSave_Click" Style="{StaticResource SaveButtonStyle}" />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="buttonItemsUpdate" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="buttonItemsUpdate_Click" Style="{StaticResource UpdateButtonStyle}" />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="buttonItemDelete" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="buttonItemDelete_Click" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" />
```

The strange problem is: if I move the blank buttons(buttonCompanySave,buttonCompaniesUpdate,buttonCompanyDelete) to the other group box, they apply the styles !. I try to figure out this problem but I don't find the solution, I even create new group boxes and buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens cause your style changes `Content` property and when you set new `Content` value, then default style of `Button` is applied which does not have any `Image` and `Label`.

Instead of this you should create `ContentPresenter` for setting `Content` property dynamically and create your `Image` near the `ContentPresenter`. In addition, to exclude multiple `Style's` you can use `DataTrigger` to change `Source` of `Image`. Please, see the following example:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffffff"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#cccccc"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="16,3,16,3"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
               BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlck" Text="Update"/>
                  <Image x:Name="img">
                     <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                           <Style.Triggers>
                              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ElementName=Presenter}" Value="Update">                                                        
                                 <Setter Property="Source" Value="/SalesSolution;component/Images/update.png"/>
                              </DataTrigger>
                              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ElementName=Presenter}" Value="Save">
                                 <Setter Property="Source" Value="/SalesSolution;component/Images/save.png"/>
                              </DataTrigger>
                              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ElementName=Presenter}" Value="Delete">
                                 <Setter Property="Source" Value="/SalesSolution;component/Images/delete.png"/>
                              </DataTrigger>
                           </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                     </Image.Style>
                  </Image>
                  <ContentPresenter Name="Presenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"                                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
               </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#dddddd" />
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#cccccc" />
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1ba1e2" />
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1ba1e2"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1ba1e2" />
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

@StepUp: I Updated  your code then it is working fine now:

```
<Image x:Name="img"  Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both">
                 <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                       <Style.Triggers>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtBlck}" Value="Update">                                                        
                             <Setter Property="Source" Value="/SalesSolution;component/Images/update.png"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtBlck}" Value="Save">
                             <Setter Property="Source" Value="/SalesSolution;component/Images/save.png"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtBlck}" Value="Delete">
                             <Setter Property="Source" Value="/SalesSolution;component/Images/delete.png"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                       </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                 </Image.Style>
              </Image>
```

Comment: "Update" means to change address of image?)

Comment: You should mark @StepUps post as answer. This site is free, currency is reputation .

Comment: When you use `TextBlock` instead of `ContentPresenter`, it means that you can write just `string` value. But `ContentPresenter` has `object` type and it means that you can set any `Control` such as `TextBlock`, `Border`, or `StackPanel` as a `Content` of your `Button`.

Comment: But the content presenter didn't give me the result I want, as the Button become not formatted well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not: Move your button styles into `App.xaml`.
Or at least into the resource section of the window:

```
<Window ... >
    <Window.Resources>

    <!--Your button styles:-->

    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Comment: You only need to do that if you want the style to be global. If the developer wants to keep the style to a control level and never intends to use it elsewhere, it really doesn't need to go into the app.xaml